# How to unpack the results from scipy ttest_1samp?

Tags: python, scipy, tuples, iterable-unpacking

Scipy's [ttest_1samp](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_1samp.html) returns a tuple, with the t-statistic, and the two-tailed p-value.

*Example:*

```
ttest_1samp([0,1,2], 0) = (array(1.7320508075688774), 0.22540333075851657)
```

But I'm only interested in the float of the t-test (the t-statistic), which I have only been able to get by using `[0].ravel()[0]`

*Example:*

```
ttest_1samp([0,1,2], 0)[0].ravel()[0] = 1.732
```

However, I'm quite sure there must be a more pythonic way to do this. **What is the best way to get the float from this output?**

Comment: Did you try just `ttest_1samp([0,1,2], 0)[0]`?

Comment: @BrenBarn that outputs `array(1.732)`

Comment: What version of numpy/scipy are you using?  For me it just returns `1.7320508075688774`.  In any case, I think `array(1.732)` is just a zero-dimensional numpy array, which you should be able to use in most contexts as if it were a plain number.

Comment: The difference was indeed in the versions, I had `'0.13.3'` and was getting `type(ttest_1samp([0,1,2], 0)[0]) = numpy.ndarray`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.17.0/scipy/stats/stats.py#L3607), `scipy.stats.ttest_1samp` returns nothing more than a `namedtuple` `Ttest_1sampResult` with the statistic and p-value. Hence, you do not need to use `.ravel` - you can simply use

```
scipy.stats.ttest_1samp([0,1,2], 0)[0]
```

to access the statistic.

---

**Note:**
 From a further look at the source code, it is clear that this namedtuple only began being returned in release 0.14.0. In release 0.13.0 and earlier, it appears that [a zero dim array is returned](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.13.0/scipy/stats/stats.py#L3126) (*source code*), which for all intents and purposes can act just like a plain number as mentioned by BrenBarn.

Comment: Note: this answer is correct, but versions 0.14 and above it is also worth checking tdube's answer a few posts down, as it makes for easy to read code

Answer (score 5):

To expound on @miradulo's answer, if you use a newer version of `scipy` (release 0.14.0 or later), you can reference the `statistic` field of the returned [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). Referencing this way is Pythonic and simplifies the code as there is no need to remember specific indices.

**Code**

`res = ttest_1samp(range(3), 0)
print(res.statistic)
print(res.pvalue)`

**Output**

`1.73205080757
0.225403330759`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the results with desired formats this way:

```
print ("The t-statistic is %.3f and the p-value is %.3f." % stats.ttest_1samp([0,1,2], 0))
```

Output:

> The t-statistic is 1.732 and the p-value is 0.225.